# Can I de-activate my keyboard with apple script?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, applescript, macos-catalina

I'd like to run an apple script that will temporarily disable my keyboard from registering keystrokes.

My goal is to make it so that my computer is logged in, but unable to type anything.

I'm considering spamming something like this code to override the keyboard

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 51
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KeyboardCleanTool](https://folivora.ai/keyboardcleantool) - Freeware.

I don't see the point in trying to re-invent the wheel ;)

Comment: How do you extrapolate that wild idea?

Comment: I've no idea where you're heading with this, really.

Comment: I give up. No, I'm not. What kind of paranoia am I dealing with here??